# How does the web container know where to fetch the default pages from?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web-applications

My Webapp is in `$HOME/workspace/WebApp01`. If I type `localhost:8080/WebApp01`, how does the browser/container know that it has to fetch index.html/index.jsp from $HOME/workspace/WebApp01  ?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining those files in `web.xml` descriptor as welcome files. Container's (Tomcat's) default welcome-file-list looks something like like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The rules container (Tomcat) uses to decided which file to load are as follows:

1. The list of files in your welcome-file-list are checked in order
2. If no welcome-file-list was specified, the list of files from the server's default web.xml are checked in order
3. If no suitable files are found, and the directory listings feature is enabled, a directory listing is displayed
4. If directory listings are disabled, a 404 error occurs (which may in turn display the page you have specified using the  tag).

Take a look [here](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.WelcomeFileList) for more information.

Comment: But when you type `localhost:8080` in your browser, you are not specifying that the Webapp01 folder is inside `$HOME/worskspace`. So how does the container know that the webapp is residing in `$HOME/workspace/WebApp01` ?